# Do I need to use a diode when combining two usb 5 volt lines?

Tags: diodes, usb

I want to use a USB bus powered device with my laptop. However, it draws to much current from the laptop and won't work. Do I need to use a diode(s) if I solder another 5 volt line powered by a wall wart to the original cable?

Comment: A powered USB hub would be an easy solution without having to pick up a soldering iron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can't connect the two 5V sources directly in parallel. You must somehow isolate your laptop power from the separate power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Common problem with older laptops and USB hard drives. You can overcome this issue with a special cable adapter called a **USB Power Inserter**. Some of these use a second USB port, others use a separate power adapter. Either way, they contain circuitry to prevent back-powering the host USB port.